# How to e-mail a check to someone

Tags: paycheck

How is it possible for someone to email me a check for services and I go to the bank and cash it

Comment: Do you need to physically visit the bank?  If someone takes pictures of the front and back of the check you can probably deposit it via your bank's mobile app.  Otherwise, if you want something you can deposit at a branch, you probably want them to snail mail it.

Comment: a lot of people check this site in reference to money mule scams. they don't know they are part of a money mule scam and the person scamming them has the pretext of "work from home" or "sugar daddy" work. just an fyi for what has been seen a lot here. if there is any similarity, stop talking with the person that wants to "email you a check"

Answer (score 3):

One way is to have the person sending you the check take pictures of the front and back of the check and then email them to you.  Print the pictures out and use your bank's mobile app to deposit them.

If you need to physically walk into a bank with a paper check then there's no practical way to do what you're asking.

That being said there are much easier ways to do all of this these days, of course.  Why would someone email you a check when they could use any number of apps to transfer it to you?